# Read cost for result set given by firebase .streamDataCollection listener?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When i have registered a listener (for firebase) through .streamDataCollection in flutter using a where query (as an example i want to read data from student collection where last_updated_timestamp is grater than 1 pm). at 1.05 pm one recode got updated and as a result listener will return one recode. at 1.10 pm another recode got updated and listener will return two recodes. My question is when second time listener return two recodes is it count as 2 reads or 1 read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are billed a read only for each document that was created or changed in the query results delivered to your listener.  The other unchanged documents come from a cache in memory and don't cost anything.

Comment: If i were using FieldValue.serverTimestamp() or FieldValue.arrayUnion() methods, how the read cost be. (i notice that when FieldValue.serverTimestamp() used this will return two recodes. is it count as 2 reads or 1 read). If i relate this one to main scenario how many read count should i get??

Comment: There is no difference.  Read about how server timestamps work: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestores-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b

Comment: Thank you very much @Doug Stevenson. This is really helpful for my work.